# Are functors that are left-cancellable necessarily injective on morphisms?

Tags: category-theory

Let it be that $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal D$ are categories and that $F:\mathcal C\rightarrow\mathcal D$ is a functor.

If $F$ is injective on morphisms then it is easy to verify that it will be left-cancellable in the sense that $F\circ G=F\circ H$ implies $G=H$ for functors $G,H$.

> My question: is the opposite of this also true?

If you can provide me a proof or counterexample then that will be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: consider the category $\mathcal{I}$ that has two objects $0$ and $1$, and only one nonidentity morphism $0 \to 1$; what is a functor $G : \mathcal{I} \to \mathcal{C}$?

Comment: @OmarAntolín-Camarena Thanks to your hint (that I firstly misunderstood) I could answer my own question.

Comment: Of course, comparing functors up to equality is "too strict". It would be better to consider whether $F$ is "pseudo-left-cancelable", meaning that if $F\circ G \overset{\alpha}{\cong} F \circ H$, then there exists $G \overset{\beta}{\cong} H$ such that $\alpha = F\beta$. I believe that left-cancelability implies pseudo-left-cancelability implies faithfulness, but I haven't checked the details.

Answer (score 3):

The hint of Omar (thanks!) helped me out:

Let it be that $F:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{D}$ is left-cancellable
and that $Fu=Fv$ for morphisms $u,v\in\mathcal C$.

Let $\mathcal{I}$ be the category described in
the answer of Omar having exactly $2$ objects and exactly $1$ non-identity morphism, and let $\iota$ denote the unique non-identity
in that category.

Then there are functors $G,H:\mathcal{I}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$
such that $G\iota=u$ and $H\iota=v$.

Then $F\left(G\iota\right)=F\left(u\right)=F\left(v\right)=F\left(G\iota\right)$
implying that $F\circ G=F\circ H$.

Then we conclude that
$G=H$ and consequently $u=G\iota=H\iota=v$.

Proved is now that a
functor that is left-cancellable is injective on morphisms.