# Are functors that are right-cancellable full, or do they have other characterizations?

Tags: category-theory

In a [former question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1197032/169789) it has become clear to me that a functor is left-cancellable if and only if it is injective on morphisms. This provides a nice characterization of monomorphisms in category ${Cat}$.

I would like to know whether there is also a nice characterization for epimorphisms in that category. I allready found out that functors that are surjective on morphisms are right-cancellable, but also that the opposite of this is not true. Are there any 'weaker' conditions then? Are these functors necessarily full for instance? Uptil now I couldn't manage to find that out, so my first question is:

> Are functors that are right-cancellable necessarily full?

More generally my second question is:

> What characteristics can be mentioned of a functor that is right-cancellable?

Comment: No, they do not have to be full. The same counterexample for rings works.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thank you. Could you give me a reference to that counterexample for rings? I am not familiar with it yet.